# Is there any Pulsar UI where messages can be updated/produced?

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

The only UI I found was [Pulsar Manager](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) , which don't even allow to see the messages in a topic.
By any chance is there a Pulsar UI with better features where messages can be manipulated?

Comment: Try https://dekaf.io/